# Removing duplicate tuples from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates, tuples

Consider the following list of tuples.

```
x = [[(1, 31), (3, 22), (29, 23), (31, 1)], [(32, 0), (34, 44), None, (44, 34)]]
```

In this list, I have values like `(1,31)` and `(31,1)` that for my purposes are equivalent. Therefore, I need to create a list from `x` that only consists of unique values. How can this be achieved? Naively, I tried solving this problem by creating a new list from `x` based on the condition that if the first value in tuple is greater than the second, do not add the value to the list or else add the value. However, as it can be seen `(29,23)` does not satisfy this criteria, but all other values do.

Edit1: The desired output should be of the following form. Each sublist must contain only unique values as defined by the aforementioned criteria:

```
y = [[(1, 31), (3,22), (29,23)], [(32,0), (34,44), None, ]]
```

Comment: Unique in each sublist, or in the list as a whole?  Can you post a desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension like so (assuming you wish to apply the logic to each sublist of your list):

```
ordered_x = [[tuple(sorted(y)) if isinstance(y,tuple) else y for y in sublist] for sublist in x]
new_x = [list(set(sublist)) for sublist in ordered_x]
```

```
print(new_x)
>>> [[(23, 29), (3, 22), (1, 31)], [(0, 32), None, (34, 44)]]
```

If you wish to remove all duplicates from the collection of elements of all sublists, use this:

```
ordered_x = [tuple(sorted(y)) if isinstance(y,tuple) else y for sublist in x for y in sublist]
new_x = list(set(ordered_x))
```

```
print(new_x)
>>> [(0, 32), (3, 22), (23, 29), None, (34, 44), (1, 31)]
```